# Why does CreateSymbolicLink() succeed, but the generated link is invalid

Tags: windows, file, winapi, visual-c++, filesystems

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    CreateSymbolicLink(L"d:\\symbolic_link_to_notepad.exe", 
        L"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", 0); // Success!
}
```

However, when I double-click d:\symbolic_link_to_notepad.exe to start notepad, an error message box pops and says the path is not found.

What's the root cause?

Comment: Windows doesn't keep extra copies of exe files around.  You created a symbolic link to a hard link.

Comment: Same here with explorer, but launches from cmd.exe

Comment: @HansPassant Creating a symbolic link to a hard link sounds exactly like what one would be doing. Please tell us more about what's going on, and why that's not "working"

Comment: On my Windows 7 computer I get exactly the same behaviour. The symbolic link is created correctly. When I launch "d:\\symbolic_link_to_notepad.exe" from a cmd window, notepad is launched as expected. But when I double click on the "symbolic_link_to_notepad.exe" from an explorer window, I get the error message "d:\symbolic_link_to_notepad.exe  Path not found". This sounds like a bug in Explorer.

Comment: Same issue win7 the link is present it works if launch from cmd, execute or even total commander but not from explorer. The link work as user but doesn't if I try to launch it as administrator.

Comment: @ColdCat: that sounds like a possible UAC filesystem virtualization issue to me.