# WINAPI CreateSymbolicLink not defined

Tags: c++, winapi, symlink, undefined-symbol

I have looked all over, and I even found something as simple as [Why does CreateSymbolicLink() succeed, but the generated link is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401414/why-does-createsymboliclink-succeed-but-the-generated-link-is-invalid) which worked. Yet, mine gives the error

```
main.cpp:179: error: 'CreateSymbolicLink' was not declared in this scope
```

Here is the code from that area:

```
if (j > 1)
{
    for (i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(filename, m[i].name) != 0)
        {
            unlink(m[i].name);
#ifndef _WIN32
            symlink(filename, m[i].name);
#else
            CreateSymbolicLink(m[i].name, filename, 0x0);
#endif
        }
    }
#ifndef _WIN32
    sync();
#endif
    //printf("Found %lu files the same as %s\n", j, filename);
}
```

Yes, windows.h is included.

Any ideas?

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866(v=vs.85).aspx) says Vista. Have you [told the headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx) that Vista functions are available?

Comment: I'm new to Windows. How do I do that?

Comment: The second link I posted has exactly how.

Comment: Does not help. I believe the problem is the SDK provided with mingw.

Comment: This is a pretty old question, but I'm running into the same problem (now with `CreateSymbolicLinkA` or `CreateSymbolicLinkW`). The problem seems to be MinGW's SDK as @phyrrus9 said.

Comment: As stated above, you have to tell your code that Vista functions are available. That involves defining `_WIN32_WINNT` to at least `0x0600` (i.e. `_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA`) before including `<windows.h>`. That gets it working under MinGW, too -- I just [fixed a bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/utils/kwsys/-/merge_requests/228) in an open-source project along those lines.